# API Key security definition 'api_key' has unexpected name or location. Ignoring

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi, drf-yasg

I am importing DRF swagger json into AWS API gateway with below config,

```
security:
- api_key: []
...
...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    api_key:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authentication
      in: header
```

However aws throwing error:
*API Key security definition 'api_key' has unexpected name or location. Ignoring.API Key security definition 'api_key' has unexpected name or location. Ignoring.*

what is wrong in this config?

**--EDIT--**

I have tried moving the root level security to operation object, further changed name of the security scheme to 'Bearer'(as specified by drf-yasg) still getting same error

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Backend API
  description: Api documentation
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: "xyz.com"
paths:
  /xyz/{id}/:
    get:
      tags:
        - api
      description: ""
      operationId: api_xyz_read
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/xyz'
      security:
        - Bearer: []

components:
  schemas:
  ...
  securitySchemes:
    Bearer:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to go away when the security scheme is modified with aws api gateway extensions.

```
securitySchemes:
 api_key:
   type: apiKey
   in: header
   name: Authorization
   description: JWT based authentication with required prefix "Bearer"
   x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
   x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
     authorizerUri: <--lambda uri path-->
     authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
     identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
     type: request
```